# How to capture that a protractor spec file failed in afterAll function

Tags: jasmine, protractor, testrail

I was wondering if there is any simple way to capture that a protractor spec file has failed.

If one it block fails when you run a test on **browserstack** or **saucelabs** it marks that as a failure. I would like to if possible capture that value in the afterAll function or some other better way. The reason for this is ultimately to post to testrail using their api.

I was trying to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/testrail-promise to accomplish this since it will do a lot of the work for you. The problem with the way they suggest to implement it within protractor is that it is creating test cases for each it block but I want to create a test case for each file and the resu

Below is just a example mockup of 3 test cases based on the filename and the results would be extracted from however protractor determines a test has failed.

---

- some_spec1.js : **Failed**
- some_spec2.js : **Passed**
- some_spec3.js : **Failed**

---

Comment: You could make your own jasmine reporter, there's a `suiteDone` event/function that gets called automatically at the end of each suite, and the object will contain the status of the spec (pass/fail).  https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html#section-suiteDone

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm currently investigating this functionality. I am trying to figure out how to get the name of the file in the reporter. That's a whole other question